# Import python packages that have similar internal module names, by full path

Tags: python, python-import

In my project I need to import two external packages from two different full paths.

When I had only one external package, I added its path to `sys.path` and it worked, I could do that for both of the package but unfortunately both packages have similar internal modules, so if I add them both to `sys.path` they will cross import internal modules from each other.

To clarify, the folder structure of the packages looks like this:

```
package1\
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  a.py # does 'import settings'

package2\
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  b.py # also does 'import settings'
```

How can I import both packages without conflicts?
I've tried using `imp.load_source` but it looks like it can only load files.

**Edit:**
When I only had one package, I would import from it using the following code:

```
sys.path.insert(1, "PATH TO PACKAGE1")
from package1 import a
```

**Edit 2:**
The directory structure of the packages is actually much more complicated than the one in the one above, and contains hundreds of files. There are also internal modules that may import `settings.py`, for example:

```
package1\
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  internal_module\
    __init__.py
    a.py # does 'import settings'
```

This means I can't assume that `a.py` and `settings.py` are in the same directory.

Comment: How do you do the imports from those two packages in your project?

Comment: @praveen When I had only one package, I'll add its full path to `sys.path` and then just do `import package1` or `from package1 import some_internal_module`

Comment: Can you show your import(code)?

Comment: does your packages have modules with same name? package1/a.py , package2/a.py?

Comment: Yes, they both have, for example, `settings.py` (they actually have a lot more in common) @praveen

Comment: _"so if I add them both to sys.path they will cross import internal modules"_ - are you sure? I though modules were resolved in the directory of the current file first

Comment: @Eric yes I'm sure. They will be resolved according to `sys.path`

Comment: Rename the module in your code: `import package1.settings as settings1`

Comment: Thanks @Matthias, unfortunately this is not feasible because the two packages have much more in common than only `settings.py`. Plus, I don't really want to couple my code with the internals of these packages.

Comment: Which version of python?

Answer (score 1):

if you import settings in package1/a.py, python will look for settings.py first in the current director i.e package1 and not package2 even if they both are in sys.path. So even if you import as (based on the directory structure you have shown above) assuming you have added pacakge1 and package2 in sys.path:

```
from package1 import a
from package2 import b
```

This is going to work without any problem and a.py will import setttings module from package1 and b.py will import the settings from package2.

If you have modules with same name both in package1 and package2, then the good way to do the imports is

```
import package1.settings as package1_settings
import package2.settings as package2_settings
```

Now you can access your variables in package1_settings and package2_settings as

```
package1_settings.var1
package2_settings.var1
```

All this will work if you have added the absolute path to "package1" and "package2" to sys.path:

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("package1")) # something like that

Here is a little experiment I did:

The package structure is:

```
package1
    __init__.py
    a.py
    settings.py

package2
    __init__.py
    b.py
    settings.py

test.py
```

a.py

```
import settings

def print_a():
    print settings.a
```

b.py

```
import settings

def print_a():
    print settings.a
```

package1.settings.py

```
a = "settings.py in package1"
```

package2.settings.py

```
a = "settings.py in package2"
```

test.py

```
import sys
import os

dir_name = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname("__file__"))
package1_path = os.path.join(dir_name, "package1")
package2_path = os.path.join(dir_name, "package2")

sys.path.append(package1_path)
sys.path.append(package2_path)

from package1 import a
from package2 import b

a.print_a()
b.print_a()
```

Output of "python test.py"

```
>>> python test.py
settings.py in package1
settings.py in package2
```

**Edit**
For such cases, the good practice is

> Always reference your imports from your top level package

You will add package1 and package2 to your sys.path and reference all your imports from them.

```
import package1.settings as package1_settings
import package1.internal_module.a as package1_internal_module_a #give a shorter name
import package1.internal_module.other_module.settings as package1_internal_other_settings
```

This way it can be ensured that your import paths never collide with each other. One other advantage of this is portability of your package. Tomorrow if you decide to change the location of package1, all the code in your package1 would just work because all your imports are referenced from package1.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. You are correct if the directory structure is as simple as this, but if `a.py` is not in the same directory as settings.py, the resolving will be made based on `sys.path`. As I commented out a few times, `package1` and `package2` actually contain much more modules and subpackages, and many in-package imports. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work but it worth a try.

When using `sys.path.insert(1, "PATH TO PACKAGE1")` it places the "PATH TO PACKAGE1" as the first place to look for the package.

So by doing:

```
sys.path.insert(1, "PATH TO PACKAGE1")
sys.path.insert(1, "PATH TO PACKAGE2")
import ....PACKAGE1
import ....PACKAGE2
```

you will have a conflict since it first will go to look at place of PACKAGE2 since PACKAGE2  will be the first item in the list...

Can you try:

```
sys.path.insert(1, "PATH TO PACKAGE1")
from Package1 import a as Package1 
sys.path.insert(1, "PATH TO PACKAGE2")
from Package2 import a as Package2
```

Comment: Thanks, but this have 2 problems: (1) This will work only if `package1` imports all it's internal modules immediately when importing it, which is not the case in my project. (2) I import the two packages in different parts of my project, sometimes in parallel, so I can't control what will be imported first.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your packages are broken, and should be using relative imports:

`package1/a.py`:

```
 from . import settings
```